# BigQuery: Querying Repeated Fields with Cross Reference

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have inherited a BigQuery table with a somewhat peculiar schema:

```
[
  { "name":"hardware_id", "type":"STRING", "mode":"NULLABLE" },
  { "name":"manufacturer", "type":"STRING", "mode":"NULLABLE" },
  { "name":"model", "type":"STRING", "mode":"NULLABLE" },
  { "fields":[
    { "name":"brand", "type":"STRING", "mode":"REPEATED" },
    { "name":"model_name", "type":"STRING", "mode":"NULLABLE" }
  ], "name":"components", "type":"RECORD", "mode":"REPEATED" },
  { "name":"ram", "type":"INTEGER", "mode":"NULLABLE" },
  { "name":"hdd", "type":"INTEGER", "mode":"NULLABLE" }
]
```

The data is structured as such:

```
hw_id | manufacturer | model | components.type | components.model_name | ram |  hdd
------+--------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------+-----+-----
    1 |       Lenovo |   ABX |             GPU |           Radeon 5500 |  16 | 1000
      |              |       |             CPU |               Core i7 |     |
      |              |       | SCSI Controller |          Adaptec 2940 |     |
------+--------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------+-----+-----
    2 |         Dell |   ZXV |             CPU |               Core i7 |   4 |  500
      |              |       |             GPU |               GeForce |     |
      |              |       |           Sound |          SoundBlaster |     |
------+--------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------+-----+-----
    3 |          IBM |  PS/2 |             CPU |                  i386 |   1 |  100
      |              |       |           Sound |          SoundBlaster |     |
      |              |       |             GPU |               GeForce |     |
```

I want to query for several components at once, e.g. find all hardware with a Core i7 CPU and a SoundBlaster sound card. Unfortunately, the "components" fields are not in a consistent order, and "model_name" can be ambiguous, so I need to query the corresponding "brand" field as well.

I am able to create a query for a single component, but not yet for several components at once. Can you hint me into the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE 2 = 
  (SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM UNNEST(components) 
    WHERE (type, model_name) IN (
      ('Sound', 'SoundBlaster'), ('CPU', 'Core i7')
    )
  )
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 hw_id, 'Lenovo' manufacturer, 'ABX' model, [STRUCT<type STRING, model_name STRING>('GPU', 'Radeon 5500'), ('CPU', 'Core i7'), ('SCSI Controller', 'Adaptec 2940')] components, 16 ram, 1000 hdd UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Dell', 'ZXV', [('CPU', 'Core i7'), ('GPU', 'GeForce'), ('Sound', 'SoundBlaster')], 4, 500 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'IBM', 'PS/2', [('CPU', 'i386'), ('Sound', 'SoundBlaster'), ('GPU', 'GeForce')], 1, 100 
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE 2 = 
  (SELECT COUNT(1) 
    FROM UNNEST(components) 
    WHERE (type, model_name) IN (
      ('Sound', 'SoundBlaster'), ('CPU', 'Core i7')
    )
  )
```

so result will be

```
hw_id | manufacturer | model | components.type | components.model_name | ram |  hdd
------+--------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------------+-----+-----
    2 |         Dell |   ZXV |             CPU |               Core i7 |   4 |  500
      |              |       |             GPU |               GeForce |     |
      |              |       |           Sound |          SoundBlaster |     |
```